# Extend Hahn-Banach to complex-linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-numbers

## My question

I have the following lemma and proof in my textbook, to apply the Hahn-Banach theorem on complex-linear functionals.

I don't understand the last equality with the question mark, because I don't know how to apply the sub-linearity of $p$ here.

## Lemma

Let $p: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be sub-linear and $l: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a complex-linear functional. Show that

$$
\forall x \in X : |l(x)| \leq p(x) 
\Leftrightarrow
\forall x \in X : |\operatorname{Re} l(x)| \leq p(x) 
$$

## Proof

$\Leftarrow$:
Is obvious with $|\operatorname{Re} l| \leq |l|$ .

$\Rightarrow$:
Let $\forall x \in X : |\operatorname{Re} (l(x))| \leq p(x) $. Let $x \in X$ and write $l(x) = |l(x)| \exp(\text{i} \alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Then:

$$
|l(x)|
=
\operatorname{Re}(|l(x)|)
=
\operatorname{Re} (l(x) \exp(- \text{i} \alpha))
=
\operatorname{Re} (l(\exp(- \text{i} \alpha) x ))
\leq
p(\exp(- \text{i} \alpha) x )
\stackrel{?}{=}
p(x)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-hahn-banach-theorem-complex-version sublinearity of $p$ implies for complex $\lambda$ that $p(\lambda x)=|\lambda|p(x)$. Since when $\alpha$ is real, $|exp(-i\alpha)|=1$, the result follows.

Comment: You probably meant |exp(−iα)| = 1 ? Otherwise the link answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: @mcocdawc, I did indeed. Corrected!